# How to "get rid of" bottom border of element inside portview (container overflow-y scroll) also has border

Tags: html, css, border

I want to create a seamless port-view which contains a list of element as images below.

Top:
[image: top]
Bottom:
[image: bottom]

I mimic collapse border and hide top border of the first element by using `margin: -1px 0px 0px -1px;`. But when I scroll to the bottom, there's still the double border (1px of last element's border + 1px of container's border). Please check the snippet.

My question is "is there a way to hide the bottom border of the last element?". All helps are greatly appreciated!

Some requirements:

1. Containers and elements must have 1px border
2. Elements' markup should be identical to each other. They can be changed by JS (It's ugly but if it's the only way to do then OK).
3. Sizes must be accurately to the pixels.
4. IE8+ compatible

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  height: 96px; /*(elements' height - 1) * page view + 1 */
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.element {
  height: 20px;
  margin: -1px 0px 0px -1px; /* mimic border-collapse & fix border-top seam */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element">EL 1: border-top of me is hidden.
  </div>
  <div class="element">EL 2
  </div>
  <div class="element">EL 3
  </div>
  <div class="element">EL 4
  </div>
  <div class="element">EL 5
  </div>
  <div class="element">EL 6
  </div>
  <div class="element">EL 7: border-bottom of me would like to be hidden as well.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can the .container border-color be the same as the page background color?

Comment: @CarolMcKay
You means to hide the border of the container rather than of the element? If I do that the container lose the feel and look of a port-view (window-like). So I would rather not to. Thanks for the thought.

Comment: `.container .element:last-child { border-bottom-width: 0; }`

Comment: @Mark I've just tested your css. The last element will be 21px height instead of 20px like the others. Beside I'm looking for IE8 compatible solution (will update the question). Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider changing up your css a little. All I'm doing here is placing a border around the `container` and applying a bottom border to each `div.element`. Just apply a class (in my example I used a class name of `last`) to the last `div.element` and set its border width to 0;

```
<div class="element last">...</div> // this is the last element 

div {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   height: 96px; /*(elements' height - 1) * page view + 1 */
   overflow-y: auto;
 }

.element {
   height: 20px;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
 }

 .element.last {
    border-bottom-width: 0;
 }
```

[jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/wimasuvini/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: Hi, just as I replied on the top. The last element's height will be increased 1px compared to the rest. For example, in your jsbin link, the last element's height is 22px, while others are 21px. The difference should be acceptable in most cases but I'm looking for solution that provides accurate to the pixel (meaning all rows must be the same height). Still, one up vote for the thought and your time. Thanks.

Comment: Ok so set `border-bottom-color: white`. That way it retains the same height as the others.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.container .element:last-child{
        border-bottom:0;
    }
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. It is currently viewed as a low quality post. Thanks!

Comment: Same idea as Mark. Last element won't have the same height as others which is designed. Thanks for your interest.